# Comparing two value in a dynamic table using jQuery in Asp.net core 2.2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following dynamic table

[image]

I want to compare the value of  `submit Quantity` textbox and `Stock` textbox together to check if `Submit Quantity` value is greater than `stock` value for all rows.

When `submit Quantity` textbox loses focus I want check, if `Submit Quantity` value is greater than `stock`, I want show an alert that  "Not enough goods exist in stock" and `Submit Quantity` textbox must receive focus again.

My HTML and C#

```
<tbody>
@{ var i = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="[@i].GoodsName" readonly="readonly" asp-for="@item.GoodsName" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="[@i].BrandName" readonly="readonly" asp-for="@item.BrandName" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="[@i].Quantity" readonly="readonly" asp-for="@item.Quantity" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" onblur="compare()" id="submitQ" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="stock" id="stock" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I have no idea how to do that

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
This is what I have done to achieve the result but it only works on first row `Submit Quantity` textbox not on second row

```
 function compare() {
        $('#submitQ').each(function () {
            let submit = $('#submitQ').val();
            let quantity = $('#stock').val();
            if (submit > quantity) {
                alert('Not enough goods!')
                $('#submitQ').select();
                return false
            }
        })
```

Comment: Did you tried something to achieve above ?

Comment: @Swati Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have mutliple elements with same `ids` instead use `class` selector .Then , just get value of submit quantity using `$(this).val()` and stock value using `.closest('tr').find('.stock')..` then simply compare these values .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.submitQ').on("blur", function() {
  //get value of submit qnty
  let submit = $(this).val();
  //get stock
  let quantity = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('.stock').val());
  if (submit > quantity) {
    alert('Not enough goods!')
    $(this).focus(); //show focus
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>Requested Quantity</th>
    <th>Submit Quantity</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="[@i].GoodsName" readonly="readonly" asp-for="@item.GoodsName" value="something" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="[@i].BrandName" readonly="readonly" asp-for="@item.BrandName" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="[@i].Quantity" readonly="readonly" asp-for="@item.Quantity" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <!--use class-->
        <input type="number" class="submitQ" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="stock" value="8" class="stock" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="[@i].GoodsName" readonly="readonly" asp-for="@item.GoodsName" value="something" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="[@i].BrandName" readonly="readonly" asp-for="@item.BrandName" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="[@i].Quantity" readonly="readonly" asp-for="@item.Quantity" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="submitQ" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="stock" value="5" class="stock" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```